# How can I access a named item in XAML flipview

Tags: windows, xaml, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I'm working on an app to display photo's with some metadata in a flipview. This all works fine, but now I want to add a Bing Map to the RichTextBlocks and display the location based upon the GPS information that belongs to the photo. In order to do this, I need to programmatically acces the bing Maps control from the c# code and for the currently displayed photo set the center of maps control to the location of the photo. It seems sofar impossible to access the Bing Maps control (named myMap) from the codebehind to do that.

I've tried to use the VisualTreeHelper and fetch the childs for the treeView, but this allways returns null.
The code for that looks something like: var x = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(flipView, 0); (using the Nuget package for VisualRTXamlToolkit.

Here's (part of) my XAML:

```
<Grid
        Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}"
        DataContext="{Binding Group}"      
        d:DataContext="{Binding AllGroups[0], Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:SampleDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}" >

        <FlipView
            x:Name="flipView"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsFlipView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Item Details"
            TabIndex="1"
            Padding="0,-3,0,-3"
            Margin="-3,0,3,0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}">

            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <UserControl Loaded="StartLayoutUpdates" Unloaded="StopLayoutUpdates" x:Name="userControl">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollViewerStyle}" Grid.Row="1">

                            <!-- Three-column grid for item-detail layout -->
                            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="Auto">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <ProgressRing x:Name="ProgressRing" Foreground="White" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsActive="True" MaxHeight="50" MinHeight="50" MaxWidth="50" MinWidth="50"></ProgressRing>
                                    <TextBlock x:Uid="Loading" Text="Loading data" Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" />
                                </StackPanel>

                                <Image x:Name="image" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                       DataContext="{StaticResource itemsViewSource}"
                                       Source="{Binding LargeImage}" Grid.Column="0" />

                                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,20" Height="Auto" Grid.Column="2">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="400" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="140" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <RichTextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" Padding="0,0,20,0" MaxWidth="400" OverflowContentTarget="{Binding ElementName=NextRTB1}" >
                                        <Paragraph>
                                            <Run x:Uid="AltTitle" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Titel" />
                                        </Paragraph>
                                        <Paragraph Margin="0,0,0,16">
                                            <Run Text="{Binding AltTitle}" FontSize="16" FontWeight="SemiLight" />
                                        </Paragraph>
                                        <Paragraph>
                                            <Run x:Uid="Description" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Omschrijving" />
                                        </Paragraph>
                                        <Paragraph>
                                            <Run x:Uid="Location" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Lokatie" />
                                        </Paragraph>
                                        <Paragraph LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight">
                                            <InlineUIContainer>
                                                <bm:Map Width="400" Height="400" ZoomLevel="6" Credentials="CREDENTIALS HERE" x:Name="myMap">
                                                    <bm:Map.Center>
                                                        <bm:Location Latitude="52" Longitude="5" />
                                                    </bm:Map.Center>
                                                </bm:Map>
                                            </InlineUIContainer>
                                        </Paragraph>
                                        <Paragraph>
                                            <Run x:Uid="CopyRight" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Bronvermelding" />
                                        </Paragraph>
                                    </RichTextBlock>
                                    <RichTextBlockOverflow x:Name="NextRTB1" OverflowContentTarget="{Binding ElementName=NextRTB2}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Padding="20,0,20,0" MaxWidth="440" />
                                    <RichTextBlockOverflow x:Name="NextRTB2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Padding="20,0,20,0" MaxWidth="440" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>

                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <!-- Visual states reflect the application's view state inside the FlipView -->
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>

                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </UserControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        </FlipView>

        <!-- Back button -->
        <Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="36,56,0,0"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" 
                    Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}" />

    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you bind the selected item for the FlipView? This could update another property that has geocode information like so:

```
private PhotoDetail _selectedItem;
public PhotoDetail SelectedItem
{
    get{ return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedItem!= value)
        {
            _selectedItem= value;
            if(_selectedItem!=null)
                Center=new GeoCoordinate(_selectedItem.Latitude, _selectedItem.Longitude);

            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }

}

private GeoCoordinate _center;
public GeoCoordinate Center
{
    get { return _center; }
    set
    {
        if (_center != value)
        {
            _center = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Center");
        }
    }
}
```

where PhotoDetail is the type of the photo in the flipview.

In your map, you just add the binding:

```
Center="{Binding Center, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

and in your flipview you can add

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
```